# Command Line Interface

Tags: programming

I need to "set up the environemnt so that the location of g++ is available from the PATH? WHat does that mean? I am new to computer science hence the jargon is still a bit confusing

Comment: `PATH` is an environment variable, usually set via shell config files. It's a colon-separated list of directories, and it is where shell or syscalls such as `execve()`  look for commands when you call them by name. That's why doing `ls` instead of `/bin/ls` works in shell. If that's your question, it's a duplicate of https://askubuntu.com/questions/60218/how-to-add-a-directory-to-the-path  As for `g++` compiler , you need to install it first, so the question is "Have you installed g++ in the first place ?"

Comment: Most likely it is a Windows question.

Comment: @Pilot6  Let's not assume There's been no indication of Windows things yet

Answer (score 1):

You are probably reading instructions for setting up GCC on Windows. While Linux does have environment variables, including the `PATH` variable, it's not needed to add GCC to your `PATH` since it will be available by default.

Simply install GCC which includes the `g++` compiler:

```
sudo apt install build-essential
```

This will install GCC and other common tools for building C++ code such as `make`. If for some reason you want to only install GCC you can do:

```
sudo apt install gcc
```

In either case you will see that both `gcc` and `g++` commands are available and can compile a basic hello world like this:

```
g++ hello.cpp
```

Where `hello.cpp` contains something like:

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
   std::cout << "Hello" << std::endl;
   return 0;
 }
```

Comment: It's more accurate to say, that on Ubuntu the location to which `g++` installs  is added to `PATH` already, not that it's globally unnecessary under Linux.  In case of `ping` command, openSUSE for instance has no `/sbin` in PATH while Ubuntu does ( [source](https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/suse-opensuse-60/no-ping-command-in-10-3-a-589542/) ). But otherwise +1'ed, good answer